# How do I handle creating a join model when neither associated model has been created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In a simplified set up I have 4 models.

- App :has_many Environments,Variables
- Environment :has_many VariableValues
- Variable :has_many VariableValues
- VariableValue :belongs_to Environment,Variable

In my react app, you create an App, then you can create Envrionments and Variables independently.  Each variable can have a value for each environment, so I create a VariableValue that has the actual value, and then an environment_id and variable_id that associates the variable value to an environment.  When saving this, and it all saves at once, I do not have a environment_id to give to the join model, since neither the variables or environments will be persisted before the VariableValues are created.  I am doing this entire save of the App with accepts _nested_attributes.  It may not be possible to do this, so I'm curious how someone else has handled this situation.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here are my models

```
class Workspace < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :workspace_envs, inverse_of: :workspace
  has_many :workspace_variables, inverse_of: :workspace
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workspace_envs, :workspace_variables, allow_destroy: true
end

class WorkspaceEnv < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :workspace, inverse_of: :workspace_envs

  has_many :workspace_env_variable_values, inverse_of: :workspace_env
  has_many :workspace_variable_values, inverse_of: :workspace_env, through: :workspace_env_variable_values
  has_many :workspace_variables, inverse_of: :workspace_envs, through: :workspace_env_variable_values


end

class WorkspaceVariable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workspace, inverse_of: :workspace_variables
  has_many :workspace_env_variable_values, inverse_of: :workspace_variable
  has_many :workspace_variable_values, inverse_of: :workspace_variable, through: :workspace_env_variable_values, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :workspace_envs, inverse_of: :workspace_variables, through: :workspace_env_variable_values

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workspace_variable_values, allow_destroy: true

end

class WorkspaceVariableValue < ApplicationRecord
  include VariableValue

  has_one :workspace_env_variable_value, inverse_of: :workspace_variable_value
  has_one :workspace_variable, inverse_of: :workspace_variable_values, through: :workspace_env_variable_value
  has_one :workspace_env, inverse_of: :workspace_variable_values, through: :workspace_env_variable_value

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workspace_env

end


class WorkspaceEnvVariableValue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workspace_env, inverse_of: :workspace_env_variable_values
  belongs_to :workspace_variable_value, inverse_of: :workspace_env_variable_value
  belongs_to :workspace_variable, inverse_of: :workspace_env_variable_values
end
```

The important thing here is that all of these models are created at the same time, not even the Workspace exists, it is all on big save, in one big transaction, my current solution is to build the workspace_variables and workspace_envs and then to associated the workspace_envs with the workspace_env_variables_values based on their index.

Comment: Could you post code of your models?

Comment: One solution is to use UUID keys instead of sequential integers. This allows the frontend to generate keys for new records. See [this](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-uuid-in-activerecord-with-postgresql/) and [this](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/04/rails-5-provides-application-config-to-use-UUID-as-primary-key.html) for more details.

Comment: @moveson That's certainly a possiblity, and even without actually using UUIDs i've considered the idea of giving them a temporary UID in react, then after saving the workspace_envs, create a map of UID to ID to then create the association with the join model

Answer (score 0):

:belongs_to can be optional, us just append ',optional: true' and you can save record into your db without any problems. but be careful about it, i.e. you leave your object in invalid state (from business logic point of view), don't forget to update saved records and add foreign id values.

```
class VariableValue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :environment, optional: true
  belongs_to :variable, optional: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but yes I'm aware of optional and I do not want to deal with the possible error prone state of the model.  This solution also still requires me to save the Variables and Environments first and then the VariableValues